# как в <audio> оставить только полосу прокрутки?

Tags: html, css, html5

Нужно оставить только полосу перематывания аудиодорожки, а все остальные элементы  убрать. Можно ли такое сделать и как?

Comment: Нет, нельзя...  Если нужна только полоса прогресса, то самому писать ее... Или же есть вариант  скрыть как то все  остальное, но это будет грубо и некрасиво...